# Pick point X,Y values getting from ArcMap window

Tags: arcobjects, c#, vba

How to pick a point on Arcmap window using with ArcObjects(BaseCommand)? I want to get X,Y values of a point. I have tried to pick point using with below code. but debugging time not showing arcmap window form picking point.

```
public ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint GetScreenCoordinatesFromMapCoorindates(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint mapPoint, ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView)
        {
            if (mapPoint == null || mapPoint.IsEmpty || activeView == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;

        System.Int32 x;
        System.Int32 y;
        displayTransformation.FromMapPoint(mapPoint, out x, out y);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint returnPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PointClass();
        returnPoint.PutCoords(x, y);
        return returnPoint;
    }
```

Comment: Please use the code format `{}` when posting your question. I updated the format of your code, but please check it whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Are you sure arcpy is a relevant tag here? It looks like ArcObjects to me.

Comment: How have you wired this event? The BaseCommand is probably not the right implementation for this, BaseCommand responds to a user click event and then stops listening, BaseTool activates and then keeps listening, it has an event OnMouseDown http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004v00000370000000 which will respond to the user click on the map, but the *real* question is why are you using Base anything and not creating an EsriAddIn? As @jbchurchill said, arcpy tag is not relevant, neither is VBA. What version of ArcGIS is this for?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have use VS 2015 and ArcGIS 10.5 Addin creation getting some problem with this 2 versions. that way I have chose BaseCommand.

Comment: According to the docs http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm ArcGIS 10.5 supports VS 2015, do you have Microsoft .NET 4.5 installed? What error message do you get when you try to create an addin? I would think that getting addins to work would be a high priority, I'm not sure that BaseTool, BaseCommand etc. are entirely supported, but like I said you would be better served with BaseTool to stay active and respond to events if you really can't get addins working.

Comment: I have used Base tool. it is working fine. thank you Michael.